# поиск элемента массива в строке js

Tags: javascript

Допустим

```
var str = "abcd123abcd"
var arr = [55, 66, 77 , 123];
```

Можно ли реализовать функцию чтобы в последствии она проверяла строку на элемент массива, и выводила в соответствии `true` или `false`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно пробегаться по массиву используя [.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

```js
let str = 'abcd123abcd';
let arr = [55, 66, 77, 123];
for (let item of arr) {
  if (str.indexOf(item.toString()) > -1)
    console.log('true');
  else
    console.log('false');
}
```

P.S. Про строковое представление через метод [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

Comment: а как можно элемент массива сделать строковым значением, чтобы он искал строковый элемент?

Comment: Добавил в код метод .toString().